# Make the path of an image absolute in PHP

Tags: php, string, path

Hi guys i have a `$string` which contains all article of a web site ,here i have the tag `<img src="non absolute path" />` i need to add the http://hostname.com before the path to make it absolute. i tried with this but it doesn't work

```
 $e["introtext"] = str_replace(
     "<img src='", 
     "<img src='http://hostname.com/",
     $e["introtext"]
 );
```

Any suggestions? I want to remember i need to replace the path in the string. Thanks

Comment: As an alternative, there's also the option of starting the url with a slash. Like so: `<img src="/images/myimage.png" />`. If your current path is `www.mysite.com/subpage/subsubpage.php`, it will look in `www.mysite.com/images/myimage.png` for the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seem right, maybe try with adding the other quotes :

```
 $e["introtext"]=str_replace('<img src="', '<img src="http://hostname.com/',$e["introtext"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you definitely have the design problems with your app (this task mustn’t be done with *preg_replacing*), here you go:

```
$e["introtext"] = preg_replace(
     "#<img\s+src=(['\"])#", 
     "<img src=\${1}http://hostname.com/",
     $e["introtext"]
 );
```

The above will successfully handle both single and double quotes and would not fail whether there are more than one space between `img` and `src` in input.

Comment: You say `mustn't be done with preg_replacing` and then you... use preg_replace.

Comment: @Forien Thanks for explaining me what I have just done.